# can ul tag be child of h4

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor 4 to convert HTML to view and Html.

The tool is not parsing the code properly please see the attached image for reference.

Do we need to do any configurations to overcome this problem?

[image: In the above image the h tag is not parsing properly]